# Getting error while clicking on custom GUI navigation item in ONOS 2.4.0

Tags: angular, sdn, onos

I have a custom GUI app created using `onos-create-app` cli which uses `ui2` maven archetype for creating the application.
The first time I run `mvn clean install` on it, it threw error:-

`Generic type 'FactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s)`

I searched online and found that to fix this I need to upgrade from Angular 9.0 to Angular 9.1. After doing so, `mvn clean install` generated the `oar` file which I installed into onos 2.4.0. The installation and it's activation succeeded.

I could see my custom gui's `VIEW_TEXT` being displayed in the navigation menu. Once I click on it, the following error comes:-

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'foo-app-app'`.

The `VIEW_ID` is `foo-app-app` in my generated gui app. I am not sure how to solve this. I have downloaded onos 2.4.0 and not built it from source using bazel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing thorough research through onos wiki docs and github README's, these are the following ways I have found to be working for me:-

### ONOS source code changes for custom gui2 application (Run Time implementation)

(Do these changes after ensuring you're in in the correct version of onos - checkout onos-2.4 branch in this case ):-

Let us say that our application has two parts, one is the backend and one is the frontend.

The backend application code can be made independent of onos source code and then we can install it in our compiled onos application as we had been doing for version prior to 2.0.

For the frontend application code, all changes will be made under **onos/web/gui2/** directory of onos source code. This ensures that we only need to build new gui2 oar when frontend code changes and not the whole source code. This allows us to **reinstall** gui2 oar in our compiled onos application.

Let frontend application’s directory be called **customApp**.

In your onos source code,

1. Go to **onos/web/gui2/src/main/webapp/app/view**  and create **customApp** directory.

   **customApp** directory can have the following structure:-

   - Create a directory named custom-app which will include following files:-

     - customApp.component.ts
     - customApp.component.html
     - customApp.component.css
   - A file named customApp.module.ts which is our top level Angular module.
   - A BUILD bazel file.

**Note:- You’re free to follow your own directory structure for the angular app as more and more components are added. This structure is what onos gui follows by default (See device for reference). The naming convention is not strict.**

2. Go to **onos/web/gui2/src/main/webapp/app** and open **BUILD** file.
3. Go to **deps** section of **ng_module** and add **//web//gui2/src/main/webapp/app/view/customApp:gui2-view-customApp** in it.
   Go to **onos/web/gui2/src/main/webapp/onos-routing.module.ts** and inside the **onosRoutes** list, add the following: -

   ```
        <Route>

      {
        path:"custom-app",
        pathMatch:"prefix",
        loadChildren:()=>import("./view/customApp/customApp.module.ts 
         ").then((m)=>m.CustomAppModule)}
       }
   ```
4. Go to top level directory i.e. **onos** and run **bazel build //web/gui2:onos-web-gui2-oar**. This will generate **onos-web-gui2-oar.oar** under **onos/bazel-bin/web/gui2**.
5. Reinstall and activate this oar file in onos application.
6. Go to **http://:8181/onos/ui/login.html** and give **onos/rocks** as **username/password**.
7. Open the navigation panel and you will see your custom gui2 app link under the **Other** section. Click on it to view your custom gui2 application.

### ONOS source code changes for custom gui2 application (Build Time implementation)

(Do these changes after ensuring you're in in the correct version of onos - checkout onos-2.4 branch in this case ):-

Let the name of our custom gui2 app be **custom-app**.

1. Create a new folder named **custom-app** and add it to the **onos/apps**.
2. Inside this folder you can have the application structure as followed in the **roadm** app inside **onos/apps**.
3. Go to **onos/tools/build/bazel/modules.bzl** and under the **APP_MAP** section, add the following: -
   **"//apps/custom-app:onos-apps-custom-app-oar":[]**
4. Go to **onos/web/gui2/src/main/webapp/app/BUILD.bazel** and under the **deps** section of **ng_module**, add the following: -
   **"//apps/custom-app/web/custom-app-gui:custom-app-gui"**
5. Go the **onos/web/gui2/src/main/webapp/onos-routing.module.ts** and inside the **onosRoutes** list, add the following: -

   ```
    <Route>
    {
     path:"custom-app-gui",
     pathMatch:"prefix",
    loadChildren:()=>import("../../../../../../apps/custom-app/web/custom-app- 
     gui/lib/custom-app-gui-lib.module").then((m)=>m.CustomAppGuiLibModule)}
    }
   ```
6. Go back to **onos** root directory and run **bazel build onos** (ensure bazel is setup beforehand).
7. The above operation will output the **onos.tar.gz** under **onos/bazel-bin** directory.
8. Copy and move this directory to the desired location and untar it.
9. Go to **onos-2.4.1-SNAPSHOT** folder(untar operation on **onos.tar.gz** outputs folder with this name, we can change this version name by doing changes in two more config files).
10. Go to bin and execute **./onos-service s** command.
11. Use another terminal to open karaf client by going to **onos-2.4.1-SNAPSHOT/apache-karaf-4.2.8/bin** and execute **./client** command.
12. In the client shell, type app activate **org.onosproject.custom-app**. This will activate our custom gui2 application (You can also skip the karaf client part to use onos gui to activate the application).
13. Go to **http://:8181/onos/ui/login.html** and give **onos/rocks** as **username/password**.
14. Open the navigation panel and you will see your custom gui2 app link under the **Other** section. Click on it to view your custom gui2 application.